# Pass in a variable instead of a static string for a WebDriver.IO page object

Tags: javascript, typescript, getter, webdriver-io, pageobjects

I would like to pass a method or a variable in place of the static locator xpath String.

The code that is working is:

```
class LandingPage {
   get enterCoursesButton() { return $('//*[text()="Knock And The Door Will Open"]'); }
   click(pageElementName: string) {
      this.enterCoursesButton.click();
   }
}
export default new LandingPage()
```

What I would like to do is access my XPath value from inside the database I created as my object repo.
so something like this..

```
get enterCoursesButton() { return $(Database.getLocator("enterCourses")); }
```

Note: the Database.getLocator("enterCourses") method already returns the correct xpath. So at this point it is a matter of passing in the returned xpath as a variable into the getter object so it can become an operational web element. Operational meaning able to access click(), setValue(), etc..

I am a total novice with using WebDriver.IO, JavaScript, TypeScript, etc... Any help is very much appreciated.

The current error I am receiving is:

[image]

[image]

I used javascript to determine the typeof datatype, and it is definitely an: object.

Another problem I noticed is that the click() method being used is JQuery, not sure if that is different then WebDriver.IO. But at one point I had an error with a suggestion to install 'npm i @types/jquery' so I installed that. This is the screenshot on what it looks like before the click method is selected.

[image]

Comment: If Database.getLocator("enterCourses") is returning a valid xpath so what is the problem?

Comment: Yuriy: I just updated the main post by adding two screenshots of the error conditions for your review. Please let me know if you need any other info ;)

Comment: sorry, I'm not familiar with cucumber related libs. Please specify cucumber in tags. For the jquery intellisense - try to reload vs code (and also make sure you are not importing jquery  at the top of the file)